# I need a specific effect 3d camera

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

Would need to animate a camera with an effect identical, or nearly equal, to this:

http://www.ambiera.com/coppercube/demo.php?demo=3rdpersoncam&mode=webgl

If anyone can help, I would appreciate

Comment: Also, the product you mention is a premium piece of software that probably took a lot of code to create. This sort of question does not belong on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you hire a developer who know's what he/she is doing. Or, you purchase Coppercube. It is not up to us to create you a multi-thousand line script.